# GCC assembly and unsupported instruction `mov'

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86-64, att

I'm trying to compile the following assembly code in `level2.s`

```
movl $0x0000000054756825, %rdi
movl $0x000000000040198c, $(0x0000000055685ff8) ; do I need $ for a memory address?
movl $0x0000000055685ff8, %rbp
retq
```

I'm compiling on a 64-bit machine, and it must be compiled with 64-bits. I have found various solutions where using the `-m32` flag resolves the issue, but again I need the compilation to be in 64-bits

I'm getting the following error messages:

```
level2.s: Assembler messages:
level2.s:1: Error: incorrect register `%rdi' used with `l' suffix
level2.s:2: Error: unsupported instruction `mov'
level2.s:3: Error: incorrect register `%rbp' used with `l' suffix
```

Errors on lines 1&3 make no sense to me because the `r` registers are 64-bits. The error on line 2 makes no sense at all to me.

For reference, this is part of a buffer overflow attack. I am placing these instructions on the stack where they are executed after an overflow return address space.

So the pseudocode is:

- place value in `rdi` register as a parameter
- move a new return address (pointing to the `text/code` region) into a place on the stack
- move the value of the address above ^^ (the `stack` address, not the `text/code` address) into the `rbp` register
- return

Comment: $ sign means a literal value, when you don't have a dollar sign it means the number is being treated as a memory operand. `movl $0x000000000040198c, $(0x0000000055685ff8)` moves one literal value to another which of course doesn't make sense.  `movl $0x000000000040198c, 0x0000000055685ff8` would move the 32-bit value  0x40198c to memory address 0x0000000055685ff8` _MOVL_ doesn't work when the destination is a 64-bit register like _RDI_ and _RBP_. In those cases you need to use _MOVQ_ (move quadword or 64-bit). _MOVL_ means move long (32-bit).

Comment: @MichaelPetch ah yes, I was mistaken about `movl` vs `movq`. Thanks! I was also unaware of the memory addressing. Everything is resolved now.